# Override titleLabel from UIButton with subclass of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I got a subclass of a UILabel:

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {}
```

I want to use this label to be the titleLabel of the UIButton:

```
class MyButton: UIButton { 

    var label: MyLabel!

    override open var titleLabel: MyLabel? {
        get {
            return label
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles in XCode, but I want to use this in a framework with Cocoapods. When I try to push it to a repository, it validates the code. It throws an error:

> WARN  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dprjfnapcavegfcniqgbxhrinmym/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/vieww/vieww.framework/Headers/vieww-Swift.h:197:63:
>   warning: property type 'MyLabel * _Nullable' is incompatible with
>   type 'UILabel * _Nullable' inherited from 'UIButton'

How do I override the titleLabel? Is it possible with a subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Change your MyButton class so that your return type of titleLabel is `UILabel?`

```
class MyButton: UIButton {

    var label: MyLabel!

    override open var titleLabel: UILabel? {
        get {
            return label
        }
    }
}
```

This silences the warning being generated. But when you want to access titleLabel with MyLabel functionality you would have to cast it like so:

```
if let myLabel = button.titleLabel as? MyLabel {
            print(myLabel.classForCoder)
        }
```

Hope this hack solves the issue.

Comment: Yea i figured this out as well :) i try to test it tomorrow if it works i accept this answer

Comment: This works but it will only work as a getter. If you want the label to be visible you need to add it as a subview to the button and setup required constraints. At least i got it working this way on iOS 13.1.